# How does the operating system handle its responsibilities while a process is executing?

Tags: process, operating-system, cpu

I had this question in mind from long time and may sound little vacuous. We know that operating system is responsible for handling memory allocation, process management etc. CPU can perform only one task at a time(assuming it to be single core). Suppose an operating system has allocated a CPU cycle to some user initiated process and CPU is executing that. Now where is operating system running? If some other process is using the CPU, then, is operating system not running for that moment? as OS itself must need CPU to run. If in case OS is not running, then who is handling process management, device management etc for that period?

Comment: This may be better a better question for Super User.

Comment: This is a question about operating system design, not a programming question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: [What mechanisms prevent a process from taking over the processor forever?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/what-mechanisms-prevent-a-process-from-taking-over-the-processor-forever) on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) is not a duplicate of this question, but should explain what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is mixing up who's in control of the memory and who's in control of the CPU. The wording “running” is imprecise: on a single CPU, a single task is running at any given time in the sense that the processor is executing its instructions; but many tasks are executing in the sense that their state is stored in memory and their execution can resume at any time.

While a process is executing on the CPU, the kernel is not executing. Its state is saved in memory. The execution of the kernel can resume:

- if the process code makes a jump into kernel code — this is called a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call).
- if an [interrupt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) occurs.

If the operating system provides [preemptive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemptive_multitasking#Preemptive_multitasking), it will schedule an interrupt to happen after an interval of time (called a [time slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemptive_multitasking#Time_slice)). On a non-preemptive operating system, the process will run forever if it doesn't yield the CPU. See [What mechanisms prevent a process from taking over the processor forever?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9354/what-mechanisms-prevent-a-process-from-taking-over-the-processor-forever) for an explanation of how preemption works.

Tasks such as process management and device management are triggered by some event. If the event is a request by the process, the request will take the form of a system call, which executes kernel code. If the event is triggered from hardware, it will take the form of an interrupt, which executes kernel code.

(Note: in this answer, I use “CPU” and “processor” synonymously, to mean a single execution thread: a single core, or whatever the hardware architecture is.)

Comment: @Gilles- This is pretty clear and the best answer.THANKS,but,I'm unable to delete my answer as it says that it'd been accepted! What should I do now?

Comment: @shekharsuman Your answer is mostly correct. Fix the part that's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The OS kernel does nothing at all until it is entered via an interrupt.  It may be entered because of a hardware interrupt that causes a driver to run and the driver chooses to exit via the OS, or a running thread may make a `syscall` interrupt.

Unless an interrupt occurs, the OS kernel does nothing at all.  It does not need to do anything.

Edit:

DMA is, (usually), used for bulk I/O and is handled by a hardware subsystem that handles requests issued by a system call, (software interrupt).  When a DMA operation is complete, the DMA hardware raises a hardware interrupt, so running a driver that can further signal the OS of the completion, maybe changing the set of running threads, so DMA is managed by interrupts.

A new process/thread can only be loaded by an existing thread that has issued a system call, (software interrupt), and so new processes are initiated by interrupts.

It's interrupts, all the way down :)

Comment: @shekharsuman This answer is fully correct. While a user process is given CPU cycles, the kernel will not “take care of any new process” — because there is no new process: a new process can only be called due to some request which would either take the form of a system call, or be initiated from some event which has already triggered an interrupt and interrupted the running process.

Comment: Well, except that a system call is not necessarily an interrupt (that's only one of the possible implementations).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which type of CPU Scheduling you are using : (in case of single core)
if your process is executing with  **preemptive scheduling** then you can interrupt the process in between for some time duration and you can use the CPU for some other Process or O.S. **but** in case of  **Non-Preemptive Scheduling** process is not going to yield the CPU before completing there execution.

In case of single Core, if there is a single process then it will execute with given instruction and if there are multiple process then states stored in the **PCB**. which make process queue and execute one after another, if no interrupts occur.
PCB is responsible for any process management.

when a process initialize it calls to Library function that's **System calls** and execution of **Kernel** get invoke if some process get failed during execution or **interrupt** occur.